# Avoid sub framework embedding iOS

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm developing a Swift framework, *MainFW*, which uses 2 Objective-C frameworks.
I imported the legacy framework using a module map file in order to use it from Swift. Here is my code:

```
module SwiftFrameworkA {
  header "../Frameworks/A.framework/Headers/A.h"
  export *
}

module SwiftFrameworkB {
  header "../Frameworks/B.framework/Headers/B.h"
  export *
}
```

When building MainFW this frameworks are "embedded", producing just a *MainFW.framework*.

What I need is that **just one** of them results embedded, the other must be also used in an *ExternalApp* which needs to use *MainFW.framework* and *FrameworkB.framework*

How can I instruct the build to not embed *FrameworkB* but using external app given *FrameworkB.framework* ?

Now *ExternalApp* says that classes are duplicated and doesn't know which one is used.

*FrameworkB* in addition is a non-modular framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the MainFW, you have to let it and FrameworkB be a sub project in an app project, then the app will compile FrameworkB separately, you just need to include the headers of FrameworkB to MainFW, then you can build your MainFW without FrameworkB inside it.

After that you can use both of them in an app project without duplicate classes

Comment: Sadly this is not possibile, FrameworkB is not an XCode project, it's a third party builded framework

Comment: Doesnt matter, put FrameworkB as the app project framework, not MainFW's framework, the points is that you dont include anything of its dependency to the MainFW project, but let the app project compile it for you

Comment: The problem is that FrameworkB is used by MainFW also.

Comment: Your MainFW only need the headers files from FrameworkB to work, you dont need link your FrameworkB source files to MainFW

Comment: so should I copy header files on MainFW and put the full framework in the final app?

Comment: You dont need to copy headers file from FrameworkB to MainFW, just copy the header path into MainFW's header search path